# How to prevent S3 from turning on when charging

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, charging

I'm trying to charge a new battery with my phone turned off.

As soon as I plug the phone in to the wall charger, the screen turns on and the phone tries to immediately boot instead of staying on the 'battery' screen pre-boot. I've tried an XPosed module to disable the dock settings to see if that was the problem but it's still attempting to boot when plugged into the wall.

I just want to charge my battery! The SuperAmoLED screens are battery hogs and having it on with a dead battery is really going to affect the charging speed. :(